# Have Input Box Appear On DropDown Select HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onselect

Hey, I have a drop down box done in html and I'm just wondering if it would be possible to have 2 separate text boxes appear when a specific drop down item is selected. 
So

Dropdown
     - Item 1
     - Item 2
     - item 3

If item 3 is selected then

input text box 1 appears    -      input text box 2 appears

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id='combo'>
   <option>...</option>
</select>
<input  id='text1' style='display: none'/>
<input  id='text2' style='display: none'/>
<script>
// Disclaimer: using a library (jquery, ext-core, prototype) to bind events and change 
// styles is safer across browsers
document.getElementById('combo').onchange = function() {
  var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "inline" : "none";
  document.getElementById('text1').style.display = display;
  document.getElementById('text2').style.display = display;
}
</script>
```